# R/C BEC with a 12v lead acid

Tags: batteries, remote-control

Pretty much all BECs (Battery Eliminator Circuit) are rated to work fine with 12v input but I haven't seen any that mentions lead acid batteries. Almost all datasheets for BEC regulators have write ups such as:

`Input voltage: 6V to 33.6v (2s-8s lithium, up to 21 NiMHs)`

Is there any concerns using these devices together with a large 100Ah Sealed lead acid (marine) battery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as the input voltage is in the specified range, the BEC does not know or care what kind of battery is connected to it.
A BEC should work fine with a marine lead-acid battery.

Comment: This. Lead-Acid batteries may go as high as ~16V when charging, but this is still *well* within the supported range of the BEC posted. As long as you are within the voltage range the BEC specifies, you are fine.